# How to group column in spark datagrid

Tags: flex4, flex-spark

I am using Spark Datagrid in my flex project. I want to add two columns under one header means I want a column grouping into Spark Datagrid. I have found many example regarding mx:datagrid and AdvancedDataGrid but I want in Spark Datagrid.How can achieve this in spark datagrid. Please help me its really important for me.

Thanks.

Comment: OK spark datagrid not support grouped columns but is there any way to use MX ADG with spark datagrid because in our project spark datagrid is already used and not want to change this if it changed then I have to change all itemrenderer, headerrenderer and all things related to spark datagrid.and we dont have much time change this thats why.

Comment: No. there isnt. Spark DataGrid is quite primitive in terms of functionality as compared to the MX ADG. You could use MX ADG in the case where you need grouped columns only and use spark dg else where. There is no rule that requires you to use MX only or Spark only in an application. We have added a number of features to all the SDK grids, but grouped columns for spark is not one of them.

Comment: Hi flexicious, you've posted [11 comments yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/users/766693/flexicious-com?tab=activity&sort=comments), and almost all of them are links back to your site or blog. If you have an answer to a question, please write a meaningful answer, but don't just spam posts with links to your blog. Please see the [faq] for more details on promotion guidelines.

Comment: 1) Did not post 11 comments 2) we do post links to our products where they are a genuine solution to the problem being presented, and many folks find it useful. Sorry, but really unsure where you guys draw the line, will be careful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a labelFunction to group two fields of your dataProvider into one column.

Example of labelFunction:

```
public function myLabelFunction(item:Object, column:GridColumn):String {
    return item.field1+ " - " + item.field2; 
}
```

The GriColumn:

```
<s:GridColumn labelFunction="myLabelFunction"/>
```

Comment: Will you please provide me a sample example link for the code you provide because I have tried this but no success. I want same given in the following link http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_09.html. Here under Revenues header Actual and Estimate columns are given same i want but in Spark datagrid.